# What is the classification of semantics into literal and figurative meanings called?

Tags: terminology

I read a Wikipedia article a while ago about semantics. It explained that each meaning of a word fits into one of five categories. For example, the word *head* has a literal meaning as a piece of anatomy. However, you can also have the *head of a line*, where *head* has a figurative meaning as the first person in a queue. The article had more distinctions than just literal and figurative.

I don't want to argue whether or not five is the correct number of categories, I just want to find the name of this concept. What is it called? Bonus points if you can find the Wikipedia article!

Comment: You may want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy

Comment: @AlexB. Funnily enough, I just came across that article the other day while answering another SE question! What I'm looking for is a formal classification of each type of polysemy.

Comment: You might be looking in the wrong concepts. Since all "meaning" is mental and not available to senses or instruments, one might do better to look at the classification of metaphor, which constitutes the vast majority of "meanings", anyway. Starting with Lakoff and Johnson, there is a lot of work on the semantics of metaphor.

Comment: @jlawler is all 'figurative'(non-literal) language considered metaphorical? I.e. is something like, say, metonymy considered a separate category from metaphor or is it one kind of metaphor?

Comment: Tastes differ. I consider them all just variants on semantic [frame mapping](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf); in semantics it's meaning that controls, not syntactic shape. And [metaphors can have multiple interpretations](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) -- too many to categorize satisfactorily.

Comment: Thanks @jlawler. I was trying to head off frame challenges and you successfully found another! While you might be right on one level, that's not the level that I'm looking for information on. The primary definition of _head_ is anatomical, however, by analogy, we can call other things _head_, because they're at the front (_head of a line_), because they have the same general shape (_head of lettuce_), etc.

Comment: I just found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphorical_extension. Explores the idea but still not the right concept.

Comment: Note that the human head is not at the front of the human body. The `Front = Head` part is already metaphoric.

Comment: @jlawler But it is at the front of a snake and many other animals.

Comment: The head of the line really has a head though. A graphical line has a tip, or end, not really called a head. Incidentally *head of the family* is the first example under the headword "Metapher" in Duden's Fremdwörterbuch (loan word dict). That example is my extrinsic definition of the word, ever since.

Comment: Yes, but German has two words for _head_: _Kopf_ and _Haupt_. They distribute differently from English _head_.

Comment: @vectory A line in this sense is a figurative line. It's really a queue of people. The head of the line is not an anatomical head. It's still an entire person in the first position.

Comment: You don't seem to understand my point. In "The umpire needs glasses", the concern does not lie with the medical condition, but it is the base of the idea and it is retained in the figure of speach, whether the referie has a medical condition or not. Fossilized metaphors like "head" are not always recognizable, then we speak of idioms I think; It may be that anatomical head had been figurative.

Comment: @jlawler *Familien-Oberhaupt* or *Kopf der [Bande]* both are in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the article! It is [sememe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sememe):

> There are five types of sememes: two denotational and three connotational, the latter occurring only in phrase units (they do not reflect the denotation):
>
> 1. Denotational 1: Primary denotation, for example "head" (body);
> 2. Denotational 2: Secondary denotation by resemblance with other denotation: "head" (ship);
> 3. Connotational 1: Analogous in function or nature as the original denotation, for example, "head" used as managing or leading positions, which is similar to the role or function of "head" in the operation of the human body;
> 4. Connotational 2: Emotive, e.g. meaning in "honey";
> 5. Connotational 3: Evaluative, e.g. meaning in "sneak" – move silently and secretly for a bad purpose

So the classification is into denotational and connotational sememes.

Comment: Fair enough. The comments are a bit heady to be honest.